# Parsing string to float

Tags: c#, parsing

I'm trying to parse a string to float and add it to a SqlParameter. 
When I enter 1234567890, it saved in database as 1234567936.
Also I saw it was converted to 1.234568E+9 in debug. Since database accepts float, I can't convert it into double.

```
com.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("Awb", SqlDbType.Float)).Value = float.Parse(txtAwb.Text);
```

Solution: Looks like I have to use another data type in database. Float values cannot hold numbers with many digits.
I'm working on an old database, so I will consider something else.

Comment: Please edit this and ask a clear question. It's not obvious what you want help with.

Comment: sorry it should be float, not double.

Comment: float has limited accuracy. If you cannot convert it to double, you have to live with it.

Comment: After reading it twice I still don't now what is the question. Downvote.

Comment: I think you're hitting rounding errors.

Comment: +1 to counter down-vote. This is actually a perfectly valid question, but it is not about parsing, it is about the limits of floats.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Float values have a limited precision... that is a *limited number of significant digits*.

If you need to store large values accurately you need to use a different field type in your database. Currency for money or maybe integers for large non-fractional values.

Basically a float cannot hold that large a number to the accuracy you want.

Answer (score 0):

[here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b1e65aza%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) is all the c# stuff about a float

`float.Parse(value)` should do what you want

Comment: should still work. as it says in the link, floats have a limited precision of 7 digits. that may be causing your problem

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, you can't get more than 7 valuable digits when you using [float](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b1e65aza%28v=vs.71%29.aspx).
Please, consider using other data type.